# how to create a GUI java for password and ID using array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, passwords

application will ask the user for an ID and password and whether they are an existing or new user. If you are a new user you will prompted to re-enter your details to confirm id and password and they will then be stored in the array.
Once the user clicks the login button the application will search through an array of IDs and password for verification. (Set your array up to contain a maximum of 10 users – given it is a small array can use linear search)
The application then will display an appropriate message.

my code so far

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Log extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Log frameTabel = new Log();
    }


        JLabel title = new JLabel("Please type your ID and Password");
        JLabel id = new JLabel("ID:");
        JLabel psword = new JLabel("Password:");
        JButton blogin = new JButton("Login");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField txuser = new JTextField(15);
        JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(15);

        JRadioButton radNew = new JRadioButton("New", true);
        JRadioButton radExisting = new JRadioButton("Existing", false);

        ButtonGroup radioGroup1 = new ButtonGroup();

        Log()
        {
            super("Week 9 Question 3");
            setSize(300,250);
            setLocation(600,250);
            panel.setLayout (null);

            title.setBounds(40,5,300,20);
            id.setBounds(52,40,150,20);
            txuser.setBounds(70,40,150,20);
            psword.setBounds(7,80,150,20);
            pass.setBounds(70,80,150,20);
            blogin.setBounds(180,130,80,20);

            radNew.setBounds(30, 130, 50, 20);
            radExisting.setBounds(90, 130, 90, 20);

            panel.add(title);
            panel.add(id);
            panel.add(psword);
            panel.add(blogin);
            panel.add(txuser);
            panel.add(pass);
            add(radNew);
            add(radExisting);
            radioGroup1.add(radNew);
            radioGroup1.add(radExisting);

            map.put("test", "12345");


            getContentPane().add(panel);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            actionlogin();
        }

        public void actionlogin() {
            blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                    String puname = txuser.getText();
                    String ppaswd = new String(pass.getPassword());

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Information", "Correct",
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Password/ID Found on System",
                                "Incorrect", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        txuser.setText("");
                        pass.setText("");
                        txuser.requestFocus();

                        if (radNew.isSelected()) {

                            }

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Re-enter your password and ID to confirm", "Information Saved",
                                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
}

            });
        }
}
```

Comment: remove `map.put("", "");`. If user doesn't enter any values in ID and password still it will say correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 char[] ppaswd = pass.getPassword();
```

instead of

```
String ppaswd = pass.getText();
```

because

> The method getText() from the type JPasswordField is deprecated.

As @MadProgrammer says:

> The password is stored in a char array and you never convert it back to a String.
>
> Strings live in the JVM for the life of JVM, making easier for nasty people examine the String pool and find the passwords.

---

Use a `Map` to store username/password.

```
 Map<String, char[]> map = new HashMap<String, char[]>();
```

put some initial values

```
    map.put("test", "12345".toCharArray());
    map.put("admin", "admin".toCharArray());
```

Here is the modified code

```
public void actionlogin() {
    blogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String puname = txuser.getText();
            char[] ppaswd = pass.getPassword();
            if (map.keySet().contains(puname) && Arrays.equals(map.get(puname), ppaswd)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct Information", "Correct",
                        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Password/ID Found on System",
                        "Incorrect", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                txuser.setText("");
                pass.setText("");
                txuser.requestFocus();

                if (radNew.isSelected()) {
                    if (!puname.equals("") && ppaswd.length > 0) {
                        map.put(puname, ppaswd);
                    }

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Re-enter your password and ID to confirm", "Information Saved",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please let me know if you want to change the logic as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it. The way you answered is clear, precise and 110% thankyou kindly. Here is the updated code now the only problem I have is what the Question states: If you are a new user you will prompted to re-enter your details to confirm id and password and they will then be stored in the array.
Once the user clicks the login button the application will search through an array of IDs and password for verification. (Set your array up to contain a maximum of 10 users – given it is a small array can use linear search)

Comment: The application then will display an appropriate message. How does it store into the array or it doesnt only when the program is ran once?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. What you want? Please correct me if I am wrong. If user is new and username/password doesn't exists then so error message along with second message to try again and next time user will get successful message.

Comment: if user is new and ID and Password doesnt exist then prompt box "Not found in system please re-enter details", ok. Then the new user ID and Password will be stored in the array. Thankyou the questions to the excercises are somewhat hard to understand, my apologies....

Comment: First remove `map.put("","")` from your code. Next put a condition before adding it into map like this `if (!puname.equals("") && !ppaswd.equals("")) {map.put(puname, ppaswd);}`

Comment: im sorry i dont know where to put the code in Next put a condition before adding it into map like this if (!puname.equals("") && !ppaswd.equals("")) {map.put(puname, ppaswd);} you are a very good person

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look on it again.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have been a huge help and great person to the world I kindly appreciate your kindness, it works well now. I do have one more question if you have time

Comment: Sure why not. Please ask.

Comment: Write a program the reads whole numbers from a text file and then sorts the numbers. Then using the binary search algorithm from your notes (week6) Ask the user to enter a number and display what position the number is or not found if the number is not in the list. my code is above

Comment: I think its completely out of this Question's scope. Please can you ask in separate post. otherwise I have to modify my post as well as comments also.

Comment: new post added: binary search from txt excercise thanks

Comment: Ah, no. There is a reason why the password is stored in a char array and you never convert it back to a String. *"The method getText() from the type JPasswordField is deprecated."* and it was done for a reason

Comment: For security purpose? Can string be accessed from anywhere?

Comment: Yes, Strings live in the JVM for the life of JVM, making easier for nasty people examine the String pool and find the passwords

Comment: Yes I am right. I am also thinking in the same way. Means I have to compare it character by character if needed.